# video gallery in magento on product page

Tags: magento, video-gallery

I am using magento 1.6.And i want to design a product video gallery on product page.So it is like the thumbnails should be shown and when user click on it,it will pop up and video will be played.Please help me with this....

Comment: What have you tried? You can customise the image gallery to display the video in a pop-up and so on...

Comment: No i have not tried anything.I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is demo you can go through 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/15764/s/video-gallery-7783/